# Is this a Secure Way to Block Form Elements

Tags: vb.net, security

I have recently been added to a Visual Basic project.  In this project, certain administrative panel require username and password access.  They current implementation is the following:

- Block all other form elements with a password panel.
- If the password is correct, the panel will be removed, uncovering all other elements.

In essence, the elements exist throughout, but they appear to not be accessible until the username/password is entered.

I'm not quite sure how secure this is, but I can't think of any simple ways to circumvent it from a user perspective, either.  Can anyone with gui/security experience please shed some light on the situation?

This is for VB.net

Comment: Is this visual studios or excel/Access?  VBA is for Excel/Access while VB.net is for visual studios.

Comment: VB.net, and I'll update the question as well, thanks!

Comment: I have changed the tags.  remember to look at the definition of the tags before posting.  It is what we filter the questions on to get the correct question.

Comment: Will do, thank you for the correction.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by blocking access with a panel.  If it just means you float a panel over them, that doesnt necessarily prevent the controls from being tabbed to and receiving keyboard input.  Making them invisible does and is possibly less 'costly' than removing the panel

Comment: Presumably these admin panels, once accessed, allow the user to load/save data from a backend database or API? As well as preventing access to the GUI, you also have to ensure the back-end is secure - it's not hard to use another SQL GUI or command line program to access the database, for instance - even MS Access can be used if installed. So users who do not have access to the admin panels should not have permissions to do any of the database actions performed by those panels, either.

Comment: And yes to add to the other comments, I don't have much experience with Forms, but simply adding an overlay over the top of them to "hide" them doesn't sound very secure at all. Not loading the admin panels in the first place would seem much better. Or at the very least, making the panels themselves invisible, rather than just putting something over the top of them. As mentioned above, I can see how keyboard shortcuts could potentially be used to get round that. And if a user _did_ manage to get round it, they should be stopped from doing anything by the backend security I just described

Comment: Yes, the forms elements are invisible as well (though I'll double check that for sure), and I'll look into the database access (though I believe that is secured, as cmd line will probably need the username and password at any point).  I know that in html (which is totally different), you can directly edit the client code to bypass the login, if it's only blocked by a form element), and I wanted to ensure there was no similar non-code vulnerability here (I didn't think there was, but I wanted to be sure).

Comment: So many ways to do this, and none of them involve floating a panel on top of sensitive controls! It's hard to say exactly how to, because different methods will mess with your UI. For instance if you have a panel among other containers and controls, just setting it to invisible would look strange as you'd have a blank space on your form. If you have a tab control, you could enable / disable the admin tab. Essentially, though, you want to set the container `Visible = False` in any case.

Comment: "I believe that is secured, as cmd line will probably need the username and password at any point)". I didn't mean a username/password, because all users would need some sort of DB account, I presume, in order to see any data. I mean the specific permissions to the tables/views/procedures etc used by the admin parts of the application, which regular users should not have. Really, you shouldn't need a username/password on your admin panels - I'd have thought users should be granted/denied access automatically based on whether their DB username is considered an "admin" user or not.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Personally I recommend grouping them in a GroupBox control, hiding the GroupBox and then showing it when the login details are correct.